# How to upgrade the pg_restore in docker postgres image 10.3 to 10.5

Tags: postgresql, docker, pg-restore, table-plus

I use tableplus for my general admin.

Currently using the docker postgres image at 10.3 for both production and localhost development.

Because tableplus upgraded their postgres 10 drivers to 10.5, I can no longer use pg_restore to restore the backup files which are dumped using 10.5 `--format=custom`

See image for how I backup using tableplus. And how it uses 10.5 driver

[image]

The error message I get is `pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in file header`

### What i tried

I tried in localhost to simply change the tag for postgres in my dockerfile from 10.3 to 10.5 and it didn't work

original dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:10.3

COPY ./maintenance /usr/local/bin/maintenance
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/maintenance/*
RUN mv /usr/local/bin/maintenance/* /usr/local/bin \
    && rmdir /usr/local/bin/maintenance
```

to

```
FROM postgres:10.5

COPY ./maintenance /usr/local/bin/maintenance
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/maintenance/*
RUN mv /usr/local/bin/maintenance/* /usr/local/bin \
    && rmdir /usr/local/bin/maintenance
```

My host system for development is macOS.

I have many existing databases and schemas in my development docker postgres. So I am currently stumped as to how to upgrade safely without destroying old data.

Can advise?

Also I think a long term is to figure out how to have data files outside the docker (i.e. inside my host system) so that everytime I want to upgrade my docker image for postgres I can do so safely without fear.

I like to ask about how to switch to such a setup as well.

Comment: Was that a typo: "the backup files which are dumped using 10.5"? Did you mean to say "10.3"?

Comment: For host based data files, you can use a custom pg_data folder inside the container, and read-write bind mount it to a host folder. Keep in mind that Docker file IO is not that good, if you have many IO tasks.

You can also have a scheduled pg_dumpall command, and just docker cp it outside regularly.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I do mean 10.5. I backuped the files using tableplus which in itself uses 10.5 driver. See the updated question with image

Comment: @VikingPingvin oh... hmm what would be a good practice then? Still better off to keep the data files inside the docker?

Comment: We use just simple named volumes for data storage in the postgres container in production. It sits inside a VM which has daily backups. I would keep the data files inside, and make regular backups just in case. Keeping them in volumes (or bind mounts) will mean that even if your pg container fails, it can restart easily and the volume will be there. Just don't accidentally prune the volume.

Comment: I am bad at Docker so chances are good I am going to say the wrong thing here. So you're saying you have one extra docker volume just to store the data and this volume is separate from the volume used by the docker postgres container?

Comment: @VikingPingvin thanks to Laurenz's answer I think i temporarily resolve my issue. but I think I want a more permanent solution by upgrading my postgres in localhost and production somehow. Do you mind if I create a new question more targeted for that and have your answer there?

Comment: my more "how to upgrade postgres in docker container" focused question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62790302/how-to-upgrade-my-postgres-in-docker-container-while-maintaining-my-data-10-3-t @VikingPingvin

Comment: @VikingPingvin I now realize I already have a named volume for data storage. And what I did was I spin up another postgres container but using an updated postgres version as image. But this new postgres container is pointing to the same volume. Then, everything seems to work as per normal. Can I ask how do you do backups? Do you backup the postgres into custom format files or do you simply backup the volume folder in the host OS?

Comment: For manual backups, I use the pg_dumpall command, which creates an SQL file.
For scheduled backups, we back up the complete VM, including the docker volume which the database uses. No custom formats used. But then again, I am not a database expert, don't really know the best practices, but these methods are simple and they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to restore a custom format dump taken with 10.5 into a 10.3 database.

That won't be possible if the archive format has changed between 10.3 and 10.5.

As a workaround, you could use a “plain format” dump (option `--format=plain`) which does not have an “archive version”. But any problems during restore are yours to deal with, since downgrading PostgreSQL isn't supported.

You should always use the same version for development and production, and you should always use the latest minor release (currently 10.13). Everything else is asking for trouble.

1. backup as plain text like this: warning! the file will be huge. Around 17x more than regular custom format. My typical 90mb is now 1.75Gb
   [image]
2. copy the backup file into the postgres container  `docker cp ~/path/to/dump/in-host-system/2020-07-08-1.dump <name_of_postgres_container>:/backups`
3. go to the bash of your postgres container  `docker exec -it <name_of_postgres_container> bash`
4. inside the bash of postgres container: `psql -U username -d dbname < backups/2020-07-08-1.dump`

That will work

Comment: Sorry, but what's "a plain format dump which does not have an "archive version"."?

Comment: Simply omit the `--format=custom`. You restore it with `psql`.

Comment: Oh my god, it actually worked. hahaha. i will update your answer with more notes and mark it as correct

Comment: casting my net wide for help. I have posted a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62790302/how-to-upgrade-my-postgres-in-docker-container-while-maintaining-my-data-10-3-t dealing with the more long term issue of how to upgrade safely between minor versions while maintaining data and schema within postgres docker containers. If you can help that would be great. No obligations of course. Thank you once again

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the need for the custom format? I usually just use pg_dumpall or pg_dump. And that creates an SQL file basically.

Comment: @VikingPingvin The custom format is much better. 1) data are compressed 2) you can selectively extract parts of the dump 3) you can restore the dump parallelized with the `-j` option.

Comment: This does *not* answer the question that @KimStacks asked.

Comment: @pablete Hm? Then why was the answer accepted?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe becaused it solved the problem that the op had, and thus the op *mistankenly* (imo) accepted the answer (it was helpful to him). Still, it does not answer "How to upgrade the pg_restore in docker postgres image 10.3 to 10.5"

Comment: @pablete You may be right. Perhaps OP wasn't trying to downgrade at all.